# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Even after adding certificate)

Tags: java

I want to login to my LMS (learning management system) account using Java. For that I have written this code (given below) but this is throwing `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`. I have added the certificate of LMS's website to `cacerts` file of JRE following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvn8MGZrhkw) but still I am getting the same exception. So please tell how can I successfully login to my LMS account?

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class A {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("url_of_lms_login_page")
                .data("username", "my_username", "password", "my_password")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url_of_home_page_after_login")
                .cookies(loginCookies)
                .get();
    }
}
```

**EXCEPTION:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:439)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at A.main(A.java:30)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Where and how did you get the cert? Where and how did you install it? Did you try using `SSLPoke` to see where in the http handshake failed?

Comment: Please check https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

Comment: @christopherclark I exported the certificate from my browser's view certificate option.

Comment: maybe there is a missing certificate in the cert chain

Comment: @RaeesKhan I would recommend against that, we had an issue where the browsers cert was different from the servers cert because there was another server inbetween that was using an older, but still supported cert.